# Screen views and screen/Session is not working - How to fix it

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api

Real time I am able to see but screen views and screen/session is zero.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question and share the relevant data?

Answer (score 0):

If no screenview event is passed while implementation then all parameters related to Screen level will come as 0.